# Show $\frac{n}{2} \log(n!) = \Omega (n^2 \log(n))$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, asymptotics, factorial

I am trying to show that $\frac{n}{2} \log(n!) = \Omega (n^2 \log(n))$ but I seem to get a conflicting result.

What i did is:

$n!=1*2*3*...*n \leq n*n*n*...*n=n^n$, so

$\frac{n}{2} \log(n!) \leq \frac{n}{2} \log(n^n) = \frac{n^2}{2} \log(n) \leq n^2 \log(n)$

And so the conclusion you come to is that $\frac{n}{2} \log(n!) = O(n^2 \log(n))$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing wrong in what you did, but you're looking at the wrong side, you need a lower bound. If something is $O(n^2\log n)$ as well as $\Omega(n^2\log n)$, then it is $\Theta(n^2\log n)$, no problem with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that
$$\log(n!)=O(n\log n)\tag{1}$$
does not conflict with the fact that
$$\log(n!)=\Omega(n\log n).\tag{2}$$
They simply give, together, $\log(n!)=\Theta(n\log n)$.

In order to prove $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously, notice that, by partial summation:
$$\log(n!)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\log j = n\log n-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\log\left(1+\frac{1}{j}\right)\tag{3}$$ 
but since $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$, the last sum is bounded by $n-1=o(n\log n)$.

---

In order to prove $(2)$ by avoiding partial summation, you can just notice that:
$$(k+1)\log(k+1) - k\log k = k\log(1+1/k)+\log(k+1) \leq 1+\log(k+1)$$
hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\log(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log(k+1)&\geq& 1-n+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left((k+1)\log(k+1) - k\log k\right)\\&=&1-n+n\log n=\Omega(n\log n).\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: And if I don't want to prove $(1)$ and $(2)$? I agree with you the first function is $\frac{n}{2}(\log(2)+\log(3)+...+\log(n))$. I want to make this term smaller, and reach $n^2 \log (n)$. this seems hard to do.

Comment: @OriaGruber: I don't get your point. Proving that $\frac{n}{2}\log(n!)=\Omega(n^2\log n)$ is equivalent to proving that $\log(n!)=\Omega(n\log n)$, and my $(3)$ just proves that.

Comment: Yes I know it's the same, but I haven't seen that partial sum before and in an exam I won't think of it. My prefered method is to lower / raise my function until i reach the desired term. I agree your method solves the question. But I haven't seen that sum before, it is not apparent to me immediately why that's true, and in an exam I won't think of that :)

Comment: One could use an integral to get a bound.

Comment: @OriaGruber: you can prove $(2)$ also with a "creative telescoping" technique. See my updated answer.

Comment: Is the above comment correct?

Comment: Obviously, the Stirling approximation trivially implies both $(1)$ and $(2)$. But how can you prove the Stirling approximation during an exam? :D

Comment: we can use it :)

Comment: In such a case, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are trivial consequences.